# Send a string of characters from PC to an Android phone using Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluecove

I am new to working with bluetooth, I have a few months experience working with Java and Android. The title of the question explains pretty well what I want to do. I am trying to do it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343369/sending-a-string-via-bluetooth-from-a-pc-as-client-to-a-mobile-as-server).

I am using [this bluetooth from Asus](http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBBT400/).
My main issue right now is how do I find out the bluetooth's UUID. I am new to this and I simply don't know how. Also if someone could explain in greater detail the code from the question that I am following, I have a hard time understanding all this client-server thing and where exactly is the string stored on the PC program to be sent via bluetooth? Sorry if my questions seem a little too easy to answer but as I said I don't have that much experience.

Comment: I managed to make the Asus bluetooth connected to my PC work using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259693/connecting-pc-to-android-phone-using-bluetooth). For now, it displays in the console all the devices it discovers and asks to 'enter the device number'. What number is that exactly? I want to make it talk to an Android phone

Comment: Also, I would like to know how do you usually find out a bluetooth's UUID?